# Merging 2 Array and Removing Duplicate inputs

Tags: java

im having a problem on how to remove duplicate value on an array,can anyone help me?
I have this code made to just merge 2 arrays and displaying the result but i dont know how to remove the duplicate inputs. (im sorry i just started learning java.)

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int[] x = new int[3];
    int[] y = new int[3];
    int[] xy = new int[6];/***new array to hold the integers of arrays x and y ****/
    int temp, c = 0;
    Scanner myInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    /*** input of array x at the same time storing the integers to array xy ***/
    System.out.println("enter 3 integers for array x:");
    for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
        x[a] = myInput.nextInt();
        xy[c] = x[a];
        c++;
    }
    /*** input of array y at the same time storing the integers to array xy  ***/
    System.out.println("enter 3 integers for array y:");
    for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
        y[b] = myInput.nextInt();
        xy[c] = y[b];
        c++;
    }
    /*sorting...*/
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5 - i; j++) {
            if (xy[j] > xy[j + 1]) {
                temp = xy[j];
                xy[j] = xy[j + 1];
                xy[j + 1] = temp;
            }

        }
    }

    /*printing of array xy sorted*/
    for (int w = 0; w < 6; w++)
        System.out.print(xy[w] + "   ");
}
```

Comment: Put the integers into a Set, that will remove the duplicates.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you have sorted your merged array a simplified solution is to not remove the duplicate but instead filter them out when printing by comparing the current value in the loop to the previous

```
System.out.print(xy[0] + "   ");
for (int w = 1; w < 6; w++) {
    if (xy[w] != xy[w - 1]) {
        System.out.print(xy[w] + "   ");
    }
}
```

Comment: ah!, yes. why didn't i think of that. thanks! this one woks..